# Delete an entire row after the values have been mapped

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

I'm looking to delete each row after the value has been mapped from this sheet to another. Below is my current code. The line `If Not IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i, 3)) Then EntireRow.Delete` (which doesn't work) is ideally where I want my row deletion to be, so that after the mapping the row is promptly deleted and the code moves on.

However I can't seem get this to work. It runs on quite a large set of data, so it needs to be simple but effective.

Any ideas of how I could do this or maybe use a Module that contained simple code?

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
Dim Slave As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Unallocated")
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Convertor")


For j = 1 To 5000 '(the master sheet)

For i = 1 To 5000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
    If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 3).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if ID cell is blank exit
    If Master.Cells(j, 3).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
    If IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i, 3)) Then Exit Sub
        Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 3).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 8).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 4).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 9).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 5).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 10).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 6).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 11).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 7).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 12).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 8).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 13).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 9).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 23).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 11).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 24).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 12).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 25).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 13).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 26).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 14).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 27).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 15).Value
        Master.Cells(j, 28).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 16).Value
        If Not IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i, 3)) Then EntireRow.Delete

    End If
    Next


    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Slave.Cells(i, 3)) Then Slave.Cells(i, 3).EntireRow.Delete
```